# Get id from json data without linear scan

Tags: python, json, linear-search

I have the following json data:

```
[
  {
    "date_created": "2019-12-25 12:57:58", 
    "date_updated": "2020-12-18 16:18:29", 
    "description": "Scala is a multi-paradigm, general-purpose programming language.", 
    "discount_price": 2, 
    "id": 1, 
    "image_path": "", 
    "on_discount": false, 
    "price": 20, 
    "title": "The Art of Scala"
  }, 
  {
    "date_created": "2019-03-16 05:15:39", 
    "date_updated": "2020-12-29 08:40:44", 
    "description": "Agile practices discover requirements and develop solutions through collaborative effort.", 
    "discount_price": 3, 
    "id": 2, 
    "image_path": "", 
    "on_discount": true, 
    "price": 30, 
    "title": "The Joy of Agile"
  }, 
  {
    "date_created": "2020-09-13 14:40:39", 
    "date_updated": "2020-09-23 10:52:39", 
    "description": "Pages is a word processor developed by Apple Inc.", 
    "discount_price": 5, 
    "id": 3, 
    "image_path": "", 
    "on_discount": false, 
    "price": 50, 
    "title": "Talks About Pages"
  }, 
  {
    "date_created": "2020-07-20 17:51:23", 
    "date_updated": "2020-08-04 12:06:58", 
    "description": "Microsoft Visual Studio is an integrated development environment (IDE) from Microsoft.", 
    "discount_price": 2, 
    "id": 4, 
    "image_path": "", 
    "on_discount": false, 
    "price": 20, 
    "title": "This Is A Course About Visual Studio"
  }, 
  {
    "date_created": "2020-07-04 01:02:49", 
    "date_updated": "2021-01-31 15:07:20", 
    "description": "Scala is a multi-paradigm, general-purpose programming language.", 
    "discount_price": 3, 
    "id": 5, 
    "image_path": "", 
    "on_discount": true, 
    "price": 30, 
    "title": "Even A Kid Can Learn Scala!"
  }]
```

I want to fetch a record using the key 'id' from the data. I did in the following way:

```
for i in data_id:#data_id is the json objects
    if i['id']==id:
        print(i)
```

How can I do this without linear scan. As if there is large amount of data, it takes huge amount of time for the last variable. So, I want the access time for all the variables to be same

Comment: can you store it in a dict with `id` as key, cache it somewhere and access it when required? This would, of course requires a O(n) runtime for first time and consecutive access would be at O(1).

Comment: Create dict from json, You can create a set of keys and use set intersection for lookup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use Pandas?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(your_json_data)
display(df)
```

Prints out:

```
date_created    date_updated    description     discount_price  id  image_path  on_discount     price   title
0   2019-12-25 12:57:58     2020-12-18 16:18:29     Scala is a multi-paradigm, general-purpose pro...   2   1       False   20  The Art of Scala
1   2019-03-16 05:15:39     2020-12-29 08:40:44     Agile practices discover requirements and deve...   3   2       True    30  The Joy of Agile
2   2020-09-13 14:40:39     2020-09-23 10:52:39     Pages is a word processor developed by Apple Inc.   5   3       False   50  Talks About Pages
3   2020-07-20 17:51:23     2020-08-04 12:06:58     Microsoft Visual Studio is an integrated devel...   2   4       False   20  This Is A Course About Visual Studio
4   2020-07-04 01:02:49     2021-01-31 15:07:20     Scala is a multi-paradigm, general-purpose pro...   3   5       True    30  Even A Kid Can Learn Scala!
```

Now you simply can select by `id` with `df[df.id =="id"]`.

Comment: I am getting the record and when I am trying to convert the record to json, it is showing in wrong format in this way: `{"id":{"20":21},"date_created":{"20":"2018-12-22 15:15:36"},"date_updated":{"20":"2019-07-09 14:52:38"},"description":{"20":"Microsoft Excel is a spreadsheet developed by Microsoft."},"discount_price":{"20":1},"image_path":{"20":""},"on_discount":{"20":false},"price":{"20":10},"title":{"20":"Microsoft Excel For Business"}}`. The `index` created in pandas dataframe is the issue

Comment: Have you tried the `.to_json()` function? Like so: `df.loc[0].to_json()`

Comment: Yeah, I used `to_json()` function. Then I got the above response

Comment: Ok. Can you give more details what format exactly do you need in the end? Isn't a proper JSON what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Use json package for that:

```
mydict = json.loads(myjson)

outdict = [x for x in mydict if x['id'] == id]
```